# How does this kind of SSL work?

Tags: https, ssl-certificate

"Issued to" and "Domain Name" doesn't match but still valid and accepted by all major browsers without any warning.

While previewing my blog post in Blogger, I noticed that my blog was previewed via SSL. When I checked the certificate information, I noticed that "Issued To" and "Domain Name" didn't match. Here's a screenshot.

[image: Blogger SSL Certificate]

Domain name was techronak.blogspot.com but SSL certificate was issued to *.googleusercontent.com and the best thing was my browser (Chromium) didn't issue any kind of SSL warning.

How does this kind of SSL Certificates work?

Comment: What does the 'Subject Alternative Names' section look like on the details tab?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Look closely at the certificate:

```
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
 DNS:*.googleusercontent.com, DNS:*.blogspot.com, DNS:*.bp.blogspot.com,
 DNS:*.commondatastorage.googleapis.com, DNS:*.doubleclickusercontent.com,
 DNS:*.ggpht.com, DNS:*.googledrive.com, DNS:*.googlesyndication.com,
 DNS:*.storage.googleapis.com, DNS:blogspot.com, DNS:bp.blogspot.com,
 DNS:commondatastorage.googleapis.com, DNS:doubleclickusercontent.com,
 DNS:ggpht.com, DNS:googledrive.com, DNS:googleusercontent.com,
 DNS:static.panoramio.com.storage.googleapis.com, DNS:storage.googleapis.com
```

Comment: Do you know why only the first item from the list is shown in the browser?

Comment: @BurhanAli Popular browsers don't show the first SAN in this situation, they show Common Name (CN) field from the certificate. This is a bug on their part, a legacy behavior that is now outdated. Lets hope they start to pick up a correct SAN in the near future.